# Node.js Socket.io Secure Authentication with Express-Sessions

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have created a login system with express, storing sessions in mongodb. I have been successful sharing the sessions with socket.io but I need to deny connections from non authenticated users. This is the code I have used so far:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
   sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next); 
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
    var passport = socket.request.session.passport;

    if(passport) {
        console.log(passport.user.username + ' joined the server.');
    } else {
        console.log('Non authenticated user tried to join the server.');
    }
});
```

From what I have found so far this works as it should but I can't stop thinking that it is somewhat incorrect / insecure?